# Ruby, take method name as an argument, then message it to an object

Tags: ruby

what is the best way to create a method with a such behavior?

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, some_method_name)
  arg1.some_method_name(arg2)
end
```

I know there should be some Ruby magic, simple and pure.

Comment: Ruby magic is often the problem, not the solution :-)

Comment: @Stefan Golden words. I will quote it and put it at my workplace! :D

Answer (score 4):

Try [`Object#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, some_method_name)
  arg1.public_send(some_method_name, arg2)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, method calls are just messages sent to the object.

You're looking for

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, some_method_name)
  arg1.send(some_method_name.to_s, arg2)
end
```

Note that this method can access both public and private methods of the class; this is probably desired for testing, but if you want it to fail for private methods, just use `public_send`

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, some_method_name)
  arg1.public_send(some_method_name.to_s, arg2)
end
```

If you may have an existing send method defined on that object, just replace `send` with `__send__`

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-send for more information

Answer (score 0):

Will also suggest to rather have such method where you can supply variable arguments to method

```
def foo(arg1, method_name, *args)
  arg1.public_send(method_name, *args) # dynamically dispatch the method with the relevant arguments
end
foo("kiddorails", :upcase)        # KIDDORAILS
foo("kiddorails", :gsub, 's', '') # kiddorail
```